# Is it possible to make reference to an unknown number of variables?

Tags: python

I'm just playing around with some code but it seemed to have the specific number of variables hardcoded.  I'm wondering how if its possible to use an unknown number of variables.

Here's a sample of the offending code to clarify(its not functional on its own, just took it out of a larger code base to show what I mean):

```
def test(a,b,c,current_total):
    a_range = range(0, target_sum + 1, a)
    b_range = range(0, target_sum + 1, b)
    c_range = range(0, target_sum + 1, c)
    for i, j, k in itertools.product(a_range, b_range, c_range):
        if i + j + k == current_total:
            counter = counter +1
```

As you can see it has 3 variables that are referred to explicated in the code, but what if its a larger list of variables.  For example, instead of `[1,2,3]`, it was `[1,2,3,4,5,6..]`

I know I can find out how many variables are in the new list(len(list)), but what do I do from there if I know there's N variables in the list? Is there a way to use an unknown number of variables in the for loop(and rest of the program?)

Comment: If there were support for an unknown number of variables, how would they be named, and how would you know what their names are?  By guessing?  This doesn't make sense.  The classic way to handle an unknown number of values is to use an array, list or other container.

Comment: For example...? How do you plan on implementing something like that. I guarantee there's another way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you *could* use an arbitrary number of arguments via *args, why not simply use a list?  It's more natural, I think.  Something like:.

```
def test(vs, target_sum, current_total):
    counter = 0
    vranges = [range(0, target_sum+1, v) for v in vs]
    for ivec in itertools.product(*vranges):
        if sum(ivec) == current_total:
            counter += 1
    return counter
```

[BTW, note that this is just an example.  If you really want the result of the specific function you gave, there are much faster ways to compute it.]

Comment: Thank you so much.  I took that code and did turn it to a list and realized I had no idea what to do with so I asked. I saw a youtube video on *lists and **dicts this morning but I didn't make the link.  I'm going to play around with it but thank you its what I was looking for.  Re:function..I'm working on a better scalable, faster, solution and just tinkering with other code right now to get a better understanding of what's going on(I will def bug you guys when I run into problems with that!).  Thanks again for showing me *vranges

Comment: @Lostsoul: the docs on [unpacking argument lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out(and re-read some of my python books as well)

Answer (score 1):

Just because I already wrote it, here's a solution using `*args`:

```
>>> target_sum = 10
>>> counter = 0
>>> def test(current_total, *args):
...   global counter, target_sum
...   for t in itertools.product(*(range(0, target_sum + 1, x) for x in args)):
...     if sum(t) == current_total:
...       counter = counter + 1
... 
>>> test(10, 1, 2, 3)
>>> counter
14
>>> counter = 0
>>> test(10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
>>> counter
35
```